# Isolate scope on parent prevents communication to child

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row" loader="loader" address-book>
    <!-- Loading complete - this should show result -->
    <div loader-success></div>

    <!-- Loading failed - this should show some error -->
    <div loader-failure>Failure</div>
</div>
```

Here, `address-book` is the main app, and the `loader` is to only act as showing an animation while the page is loading. The content of the address-book would go into `loader-success` and the failure message (that is, if no content found) would go inside `loader-failure`.

So my idea was to use the following directives:

```
app.directive('loader', function($compile, $timeout)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            loader: '&'
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<div class="row" ng-if="loading">' + 
            '   <div class="small-15 columns text-center">' +
            '       <i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.loading = true;
            scope.failure = false;
            scope.success = false;

            scope.$watch('loader', function(fn) {
                if (_.isFunction(fn)) {
                    scope.loader()
                    .then(function(){
                        scope.success = true;
                        scope.loading = false;
                        scope.$safeApply();
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        scope.failure = true;
                        scope.loading = false;
                        scope.$safeApply();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

where `scope.loader` is the promise of the `$q` set from `address-book`. The promise is resolved/rejected after the address-book tries to get content.

For the success/failure blocks I have:

```
app.directive('loaderFailure', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.hide();
            scope.$watch('failure', function(value) {
                if (_.isTrue(value)) {
                    element.show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('loaderSuccess', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.hide();
            scope.$watch('success', function(value) {
                if (_.isTrue(value)) {
                    element.show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, because of the isolate scope on `loader`, the scopes of the two children `loader-success` and `loader-failure` can no longer read the parent's. I cannot use the `$compile` on `loader` because that would then take the scopes out of the address-book's app.

What can I do?

Comment: scope.$parent.$watch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use events. If you want to send some date from children to parent use `$scope.$emit`.

From parent to children `$scope.$broadcast` - can have negative performance impact

It it good approach to use events when you want to communicate between components that are loosely coupled.

See more info about events:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Comment: I thought about this. But I was hoping to do that without using `$emit` or `$broadcast`, as these are frowned upon.

Comment: For the time being, I am using `$emit` with a bit of modification (see my answer). I'm gonna leave this post open to see if it can be done without that.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using `$emit`. However, since my `loader` directive can be used on multiple different components on the same page, it was important to be able to distinguish between the two. Also, the `loader` is added to an element with another directive running on it.

To fix these issues, this is what I did:

Failure

The `channel` is then used as a unique identifier. It can even be the `$id` of the other directive scope to ensure that it is completely unique. Now, the directives are as follows:

```
app.directive('loader', function($compile, $rootScope)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            loader: '&',
            channel : '@loaderChannel'
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<div class="row" ng-if="loading">' + 
            '   <div class="small-15 columns text-center loader">' +
            '       <i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.loading = true;

            scope.$watch('loader', function(fn) {
                if (_.isFunction(fn)) {
                    scope.loader()
                    .then(function(){
                        scope.loading = false;
                        $rootScope.$emit('LOADER_SUCCESS', scope.channel);
                        scope.$safeApply();
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        scope.loading = false;
                        $rootScope.$emit('LOADER_FAILURE', scope.channel);
                        scope.$safeApply();
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    };
});

app.directive('loaderFailure', function($rootScope)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.hide();
            $rootScope.$on('LOADER_FAILURE', function(event, channel) {
                if (channel == attrs.loaderFailure) element.show();
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('loaderSuccess', function($rootScope)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.hide();
            $rootScope.$on('LOADER_SUCCESS', function(event, channel) {
                if (channel == attrs.loaderSuccess) element.show();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Basically, I `$emit` the success or failure with the channel. And the `loader-success` and `loader-failure` listen to these broadcasts, match their channel it and behave accordingly.

In each component then, I simply define `scope.loader = $q.defer()` and resolve/reject it when I need.